# R, two layered histogram in one plot

Tags: r, histogram

```
seed_ant <- read.table(...)
thatch_ant <- read.table(...)
seed_mass <- seed_ant$Mass
seed_mass[578:1195] <- 0
thatch_mass <- thatch_ant$Mass
combined <- cbind(seed_mass, thatch_mass)
combined_mass <- data.frame(combined)
ggplot(combined_mass, aes(x=combined, ylilm=c(0,350))) + 
    geom_histogram(alpha=0.2, position="identity")
```

I made seed_mass 578:1195, equals to 0 because the lengths of seed_mass and thatch_mass are different.

I'm having problem with the ggplot, the above code returns error of 'Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1195): x, ylilm'

I would like two histograms would be formed by seed_mass and thatch_mass and the y axis to be the range of the max and min of the mass

but my ggplot returns error 'Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1195): x, ylilm'

Comment: what happens when you remove `ylilm=c(0,350)`  ?  Also I am not sure about this one `combined_mass <- data.frame(combined_mass)`. Was it suppoae to be `combined_mass <- data.frame(combined)`?

Comment: You can't shorten a vector by setting its values to `0`. Try `seed_mass <- seed_mass[1:length(thatch_mass)]` instead.

Comment: i just don't know what to put 'dat' so i just made a data frame of combined_mass, i know its wrong, what should i put for dat and x = ??

Comment: i didn't shorten them i just wanted to make length of send_mass to be equaled to thatch_mass,

Comment: You can leave data = Null. Something like `ggplot( , aes( x = .... ))`

Comment: @TalJ.Levy that returns  error, Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2390): x, ylilm

Comment: Did you mean removing `ylim` returns an error?

Comment: @TalJ.Levy I don't know,,  i just changed y=0:350 and returns Error in aes(x = combined, y = 0:350) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2, position = "identity") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @TalJ.Levy no i removed dat leave like ( , as (x = ...)))

Comment: Now last thing. Histogram cannot have a `y` in `aes`. Also `x` needs to be a 1D vector. Yours is a 2D object. In that case you need to factor to group by but you do not have one. So you can create a col that is 2*1195 in length,. 1195 entries are "A" and the rest "B". The other column will be both seed_mass and thatch_mass. Then you can use `ggplot( , aes(x = .., fill = colA-B))...`

Comment: @TalJ.Levy so do you mean i need to make combined as length of 2*1195 and label them as A and B?  how can i make entries?

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I hope this can help you out

```
A <- rnorm(1000)  # this is seed_mass
B <- rexp(1000) # this is thatch_mass

colB <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 1000) # this is to tell them apart
colA <- c(A,B) # combine them together
dt <- data.frame(colA, colB) # create Data frame
ggplot(dt, aes(x = colA, fill = colB)) + 
  geom_histogram(col = "black", alpha = 0.5, 
                 position = "identity") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "your title", 
                      breaks=c("A", "B"), 
                      labels = c("1","2")) # plot
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm really sorry for bothering you, Can I ask you one question more?

Comment: Of course. Any one who can help will love to do that

Comment: colB <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 1000), for this code, is there any other way that set A to 1:577 and B to 578:1772 ?? because i set the send_mass 578:1195 to be 0 to make the length equal to thatch_mass, however on the histogram I have highly frequency of 0

Comment: Correct, remove those zeros. Easiest way is `colB <- c( rep("A", 577), rep("B" , 1195) )`. Note that 577 snd 1195 simply correspond to the lengths of your two vectors.

Comment: thx so much... I really appreciate your help, I was struggling this for two days

Comment: do you know how to add legend,,,? I tried other ways on stack flow but not working for mine,, sorry

Comment: @Joe, I edited the answer to show you how to add and control your legend. Also, just wanted to say that the following command: `colB <- c( rep("A", 577), rep("B" , 1195) )` could also be achieved this way: `colB <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], c(577,1195))`. Hope it helps.